# F# function, how it really works

Tags: f#

I got function like this one.

```
let c = (fun a b ‐> let d = a 10 in d ‐ 4*b) (fun c ‐> c + c) 5
let x = c‐6
```

That's what I understand so far:
"fun c ‐> c + c" is first argument for "fun a b" and "5" is second.
"let d" is kind a function that takes "a" and "b" and returns the result.
But if somebody could explain what exactly happened in:

```
let d = a 10 in d ‐ 4*b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in` is used here as part of [*verbose syntax*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/verbose-syntax). You can rewrite it in *leightweight syntax* to make it a bit more readable. It would be something like that:

```
fun a b =
    let d = a 10
    d - 4 * b
```

`a` is invoked with `10` as argument and the results is assigned to `d`. Later on `d - 4 * b` is calculated and returned from the function.

For the example you have `a` is `fun c -> c + c` so invoking it with `10` returns `20`.

`20 - 4 * 5 = 0` so `c` is set to `0` and `x` will be `0 - 6 = -6`.

From F# interactive:

```
> let c = (fun a b -> let d = a 10 in d - 4*b) (fun c -> c + c) 5;;
val c : int = 0
```

Comment: I did not consider the possibility that "a" could be a function and takes "10" as an argument. Thanks, that really helped me.